# How to remove files from Unstage | GitHub Desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

Im using [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) and i have many files that was cache/test/backup that i added or delete, now this files stay in change tab but i want to remove this files because i dont need to commit them.

How to remove all thoes files that i dont want to commit from change tab

i tried with discard changes but then files are back to my local project i just want to remove them

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a `git reset some-file` to me (that will get the **changes** on that file out of the index).

Comment: i have 65 files there should i do it one by one ? or there is a way to remove them all

Comment: You can remove **all changes** on the index with `git reset .` (run at the root of the project).

Answer (score 0):

These files are versioned, you want to tell git to remove them from versioning. The cli command for that is `git rm` (or `git rm --cached`)

---

From the command line: run

```
git rm --cached -r vqmod/vqcache
git commit
```

From github desktop:

look for an option that indicates "remove this file" or "remove this directory".